# Calcular Intervalo de Horas

Tags: php

Preciso calcular o intervalo de minutos entre duas datas.
Meu problema está sendo calcular quando passa um dia.

Exemplo:

```
Primeira Data -> 2016-11-18 15:20:00;
Segunda Data -> 2016-11-18 15:45:02;
```

Comment: Você precisa saber a diferença em minutos entre as datas ?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo!

Comment: Já tem algum código feito ?

Comment: Tenho, $horario1 = "13:10:50";
$horario2 = "13:40:00";
echo "Diferença entre horários: " . dif_horario($horario1, $horario2). "<br/>";

// Função para calcular horário
function dif_horario($horario1, $horario2) {
    $horario1 = strtotime("1/1/1980 $horario1");
    $horario2 = strtotime("1/1/1980 $horario2");
         
 if ($horario2 < $horario1) {
    $horario2 = $horario2 + 86400;
 }
  
$valor = (($horario2 - $horario1) / 3600) * 60;  
return ceil($valor);    
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma boa solução para verificar isso é usar `strtotime();` (claro) e `abs();`

```
$t1 = strtotime("18-11-2016 15:12:00");
$t2 = strtotime("18-11-2016 15:30:00");
echo round(abs($t1 - $t2) / 60,2). " minutos ";
```

Além da solução do Erlon, você pode usar essa também.

Comment: Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva, quando notar uma pergunta que provavelmente já tem respostas no site, favoreça as respostas existentes nas perguntas antigas, assim evita que o conteúdo fique espalhado. Para isto basta votar ou sinalizar como duplicata, vale até apontar o link nos comentários.

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme. No caso, quando foi marcada como duplicada, eu já tinha postado. O certo seria apagar ?

Comment: Não é isso que eu quis dizer, a ação que recomendei foi antes de duplicar, no caso você mesmo pode pesquisar se a pergunta já não foi respondida, ainda mais uma pergunta simples assim provavelmente já terá resposta. A questão é favorecer as respostas existentes

Comment: Obs: Não precisa apagar esta, a dica é para futuras postagens.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php)

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2016-11-18 15:20:00');
$datetime2 = date_create('2016-11-18 15:45:02');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

### O código acima irá retornar

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 25
    [s] => 2
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

Comment: Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva, quando notar uma pergunta que provavelmente já tem respostas no site, favoreça as respostas existentes nas perguntas antigas, assim evita que o conteúdo fique espalhado. Para isto basta votar ou sinalizar como duplicata, vale até apontar o link nos comentários.

Answer (score 2):

```
$datatime1 = strtotime('2016-11-18 15:20:00');
$datatime2 = strtotime('2016-11-18 15:45:02');
$segundos = ($datatime2 - $datatime1);
$inteiro = (int)($segundos / 60);
$resto = ($segundos-($inteiro*60));
echo "A diferença em minutos é { ".$inteiro." } minutos e " .$resto. " segundos";
```

Comment: Por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva, quando notar uma pergunta que provavelmente já tem respostas no site, favoreça as respostas existentes nas perguntas antigas, assim evita que o conteúdo fique espalhado. Para isto basta votar ou sinalizar como duplicata, vale até apontar o link nos comentários.